# Prevent folder made using python from deletion/modification

Tags: python, windows

I have an app where I create folders for projects data. I want be able to prevent normal user (using file explorer) from deletion/modification of used folder. App should have normal access to the folder. What is the easiest way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set read only flag on your folder when creating https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir or after creating using https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod, or if you dont need such drastic methods you can find a way to make it not visible that way "normal user" wont find it.